# Python: How to extract url and decode it?

Tags: python, http, url, decode

I am getting response from a API as follows-

```
def update_csv(products):
print type(products)
print products
[{u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBHdbRqB7F6aMKM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F1.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQDx7P52g0NYBB-3', u'id': u'1411912028843607', u'retailer_id': u'product-1'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDyc-Yyic5QLOqH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F0.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQDhmhPJxFZEpMFX', u'id': u'993388404100117', u'retailer_id': u'product-0'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB69V2cgASUIci1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F100.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQAk3eZ4vqWYbOW4', u'id': u'1347112758661660', u'retailer_id': u'product-100'}, {u'image_url': u'https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBM75VZTNuxqaoq&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F10.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQAUdkc6II5eu47D', u'id': u'1358784964179738', u'retailer_id': u'product-10'}]
```

I want to extract all the urls from this which contains `.png` and decode that url

As you can this in the above url it contains `http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F1.png`
I want to extract all these url and decode and save as a list.

**What I tried**

```
image_urls = ""
for product in products:
        image_urls += urllib.unquote(product['image_url'].split("=")[2])+"\n"
```

The problem with this is it doesn't remove "&cfs" form the url

```
http://gigya.jp/dpa/1.png&cfs
http://gigya.jp/dpa/0.png&cfs
http://gigya.jp/dpa/100.png&cfs
http://gigya.jp/dpa/10.png&cfs
```

Sorry I new to python. Is there any efficient way to do this?
Please help.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I added what I tired. Please don't downvote. Please check again.

Comment: You can split again on `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `urlparse`, which makes this a lot simpler:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> for i in products:
...    print(urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(i['image_url']).query)['url'][0])
...
http://gigya.jp/dpa/1.png
http://gigya.jp/dpa/0.png
http://gigya.jp/dpa/100.png
http://gigya.jp/dpa/10.png
```

For Python 3, use `urllib.parse`:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> for i in products:
...    print(parse_qs(urlparse(i['image_url']).query)['url'][0])
...
http://gigya.jp/dpa/1.png
http://gigya.jp/dpa/0.png
http://gigya.jp/dpa/100.png
http://gigya.jp/dpa/10.png
```

Comment: What is this key 'url'?

Comment: It is part of what `parse_qs` returns. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) for more.

Comment: If I decode 'image url' I found it like below https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB69V2cgASUIci1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgigya.jp%2Fdpa%2F100.png&cfs=1&_nc_hash=AQAk3eZ4vqWYbOW4

Comment: Can I use regex like &url.*(.png)

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression when there is a perfectly valid standard library method that works?